# Round corner shape RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-relativelayout

I am working on layout on `Android` project. 
Where the layout parameters are coming programmically. My current layout is coming -

[image]

**Code**-

```
mRedBackground=initBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_red_80), this.mWidthScreen, (int)(0.0984375F * this.mWidthScreen), 0, 0);
```

And **initBackground** looks like-

```
public RelativeLayout initBackground(int intColor, int intWidthscreen, int intHeight, int intMerginLeft, int intMerginTop)
  {
    RelativeLayout localRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this.mContext);
    if (intColor != 0)
    localRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(intColor);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(intWidthscreen, intHeight);
    localLayoutParams.setMargins(intMerginLeft, intMerginTop, 0, 0);
    localRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams);
    return localRelativeLayout;
  }
```

But I need it in rounded shape. something like-  [image]

I can not use other than **RelativeLayout** due to project restriction. I also can not use **Background XML** also. All I need to set from code. I am sorry for that. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: see `GradientDrawable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(Color.RED);
gd.setCornerRadius(10);
gd.setStroke(2, Color.WHITE);

view.setBackground(gd);
```